# Helm template cannot use index along with if or statement

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have attributes that include dashes in their names, which I don't have any issue while using them along with `index` i.e:

```
{{ toYaml index .Values.myService "my-service-config" | b64enc }}
```

However, if I want to use an `if or` for multiple evaluations, I cannot successfully use index for them, i.e:

```
{{- if or index .Values.serviceA.appyml .Values.serviceB.log4j2xml .Values.serviceC "some-service-configyml" .Values.serviceC "another-serviceyml" }}
```

I receive the error message:

```
at <index>: wrong number of args for index: want at least 1 got 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `index` for each attribute name having dashes within parentheses:

```
{{- if or .Values.serviceA.appyml .Values.serviceB.log4j2xml ( index .Values.serviceC "some-service-configyml") ( index .Values.serviceD "another-serviceyml") }}
```